# Assigning keys to values from external command results

Tags: perl

I am stuck. I run a command from an external tool. The output from this tool is in the following format:

```
{
 {
   Dan Summers

   Male
   Funds less than $100
   March 23, 2021 1:58:24 PM
   Undisclosed
 }
 {
   Susan August

   Female
   no funds
   March 23, 2021 7:58:24 AM
   Expired
 }
}
```

I need to assign a key to the values in order to do some matching later on and also print it as a single line but I am not sure how to do this.
First I did some search and replace to make it single lines. but then it dawned on me that I still do not have a way to add keys. as an Example to what I did:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $result = `command`;
$result =~ s/\n//g;
print "$result";
```

which gave me a result of:

```
{ {   Dan Summers   Male   Funds less than $100   March 23, 2021 1:58:24 PM   Undisclosed } {   Susan August   Female   no funds   March 23, 2021 7:58:24 AM GMT+02:00   Expired }}
```

Then I tried adding keys before even attempting to make it a string, but obviously this is not an split array, so using `$arr[0]` will not work.. so we all know how this went:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @result = `command`;
for my $res(@result) {
    print "line: $res[0]"
}
```

How can I add keys so I can get something similar to a JSON result? Something like:

```
{
 {
   name: Dan Summers
   gender: Male
   fundstatus: Funds less than $100
   updated: March 23, 2021 1:58:24 PM
   status: Undisclosed
 } ....
```

Would really appreciate some guidance here.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention. The external tool does not have any matching criteria to search for a username or anything of that sort. If you run the tool and 10 people are in the result, it will print all 10 in the format of the first example.. Just as an FYI, so there is no way to extract only detail where user is "Dan Summers".

That is sort of why I am doing this, so I can build this functionality outside of the tool.

Comment: Do you want to process this data in the same program?

Comment: Hi @simbabque. Thank you for your response. I cannot, the tool is outside of my control, so I just need to extract the data and then using perl I will then insert the data into a database, but I need to keys to do that.

Comment: That's what I meant. So you get this data, but all processing AFTERWARDS is in your code?

Comment: Correct Yes, @simbabque.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about JSON as such. Do you know that the order of the rows/fields is always the same?

Comment: @simbabque. The order is always the same yes. I am not really worried about JSON so much, it just resembled JSON a bit, but without the keys.

Comment: It sort of does, but also doesn't. It has no quotes, and JSON objects are unordered. This is more like a CSV file that's gone vertical. I'm writing code now.

Comment: @simbabque, wow, that is actually a great way to put it... _"CSV gone vertical"_

Comment: If you chuck the outer braces, you basically have a record-start and a record-end, and then you just need to split and remove whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the whole thing like it's a CSV file with really odd delimiters. Your record delimiter is the combination of `}{` and whitespace. Your field delimiter is a line break. Either clean the surrounding brackets up or ignore them.

My code doesn't do any input format validation, but gives you the values you need for processing into DBI.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# replace with your shell-out
my $input = do { local $/ = undef; <DATA> };


foreach my $record ( split '}', $input) {
    my ($name, $gender, $fundstatus, $updated, $status) = grep {/[^{}\s]/ } split "\n", $record;

    next unless $name;

    # ...
}


__DATA__
{
 {
   Dan Summers

   Male
   Funds less than $100
   March 23, 2021 1:58:24 PM
   Undisclosed
 }
 {
   Susan August

   Female
   no funds
   March 23, 2021 7:58:24 AM
   Expired
 }
}
```